# Enumeration of Hurwitz quaternions of norm p

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

In "on Quaternions and Octonions" by Conway and Smith, they quote a result by which for each prime norm $p$ there are exactly $p+1$ Hurwitz quaternions of norm $p$. I haven't found any proof of that. Any references or directions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of [Jacobi's four-square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem). See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84897/proofs-of-jacobis-four-square-theorem) for a disussion of various proofs.